# How can I use JToken with protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

My model is as per below:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> Data { get; } = new();
}
```

but if I try to serialize it, it complains:

> Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: Nested or jagged lists, arrays and maps are not supported: Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken

example:

```cs
var obj = new Foo
{
    Data =
    {
        ["abc"] = JToken.Parse(@"{""a"":true}"),
        ["def"] = JToken.Parse(@"null"),
        ["ghi"] = JToken.Parse(@"true"),
        ["jkl"] = JToken.Parse(@"[{},12.3,'abc']"),
    }
};
var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(obj); // <=== throws here
foreach (var (key, value) in clone.Data)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {value.ToString(Formatting.None)}");
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

`JToken` is not, by itself, particularly friendly for protobuf-net:

1. `JToken : IEnumerable<JToken>`, and protobuf-net wants to treat that as a list by default (hence the mention of "jagged" / "nested" repeated data)
2. there isn't an obvious protobuf encoding of JSON data, at least: not one that leaps out to the serializer

protobuf-net doesn't have inbuilt custom handling for `JToken`, as that would force it to take a dependency on libraries that the consumer *might not be using*.
Fortunately, we *can* fix this, by providing a custom serializer:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Integrates with protobuf-net to serialize JToken as strings
/// </summary>
sealed class ProtobufNetJTokenSerializer : ISerializer<JToken>
{
    public static void Configure(RuntimeTypeModel? model = null)
    {
        var config = (model ?? RuntimeTypeModel.Default).Add<JToken>(false);
        config.IgnoreListHandling = true;
        config.SerializerType = typeof(ProtobufNetJTokenSerializer);
    }

    SerializerFeatures ISerializer<JToken>.Features
        => SerializerFeatures.CategoryScalar | SerializerFeatures.WireTypeString;

    JToken ISerializer<JToken>.Read(ref ProtoReader.State state, JToken value)
        => JToken.Parse(state.ReadString());

    void ISerializer<JToken>.Write(ref ProtoWriter.State state, JToken value)
        => state.WriteString(value.ToString(Formatting.None));
}
```

If we look at `Configure`:

- `RuntimeTypeModel.Default` is simply the default model, the one you talk to when using simple APIs like `Serializer.DeepClone`
- the `Add<JToken>(false)` adds `JToken` to the model, but tells it not to even try applying any normal conventions
- the `IgnoreListHandling = true` suppresses the handing of `IEnumerable<T>`
- the `SerializerType = ...` configures a custom serializer (`ISerializer<JToken>`) for this type

We tell it that we're going to be serializing a scalar string value, i.e. "just a string". In the `Write` method we can use `JToken`'s `ToString` *with a `Formatting` specified* (without this, `"null"`, `"true"`, etc get odd treatment, and it defaults to a layout that includes unnecessary whitespace). We pair this with `JToken.Parse` in the `Read` method.

The result is that it works as we would hope! We just add `ProtobufNetJTokenSerializer.Configure();` (or `ProtobufNetJTokenSerializer.Configure(someModel);` if you're using a specific model, for more advanced scenarios) somewhere near the app-startup (before serialization has been attempted), and it works as we expect, with console output:

```
abc: {"a":true}
def: null
ghi: true
jkl: [{},12.3,"abc"]
```

(note that the order in dictionaries is not guaranteed, so the order of the lines *could* change, in theory)